# How do I access files generated during Cloud Run function execution?

Tags: selenium, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm running a very simple program [getting screenshots of a page using Selenium](https://dev.to/googlecloud/using-headless-chrome-with-cloud-run-3fdp) in Cloud Run. I know that Cloud Run is stateless and I cannot access the screenshot that is generated after the program finishes executing, but I wanted to know where/how can I access these files right after the screenshot is taken and read them, so I can store a reference to them in my Cloud Storage bucket too

Answer (score 0):

You have several solution:

- Store the screenshot locally, and then upload them to Cloud Storage (you can create a script for that, use client libraries,...). A good evolution is to make a tar (optionally a gzip also) to upload only 1 file, it's faster.
- Use Cloud Run execution runtime 2nd generation, and mount a bucket with [GCSFuse into your Cloud Run instance](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/network-filesystems-fuse). Like that, a file directly written in the mounted directory will be written on Cloud Storage. For that solution, and despite the good tutorial, it requires good skills in container.